# How to switch to a remote branch with a forward slash in the branch name?

Tags: git

I'm trying to checkout to a remote branch, but if there is a slash in the branch name this doesn't work:

```
$ git checkout --track origin/feat/add_posts
fatal: 'origin/feat/add_posts' is not a commit and a branch 'feat/add_posts' cannot be created from it
```

The solution to this problem is a little longer and may lead to some errors because I need to know what is the parent of the branch that I need to switch to so that there are no conflicts.

Commands `for-each-ref` show:

```
git for-each-ref | grep feat/add_posts
369006c638a0db7c344d3d6b66c08945c273d4ee commit refs/heads/feat/add_posts
f5ee8ce4c7f9b8213fa33f4abb88d8d13625ca62 commit refs/remotes/origin/feat/add_posts
```

I use:

```
git checkout -b feat/add_posts
git pull origin feat/add_posts
git reset --hard origin/feat/add_posts
```

And it works, but is there an easier way?

**Updated**: it shows only in the first time(if i didn't have this branch), so if I have this branch in the past but i remove it, I could just checkout to it without any problem.

```sh
git checkout feat/add_posts
Branch 'feat/add_posts' set up to track remote branch 'feat/add_posts' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'feat/add_posts'
```

Comment: `git checkout feat/add_posts`?

Comment: Show error: `error: pathspec 'feat/add_posts' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Comment: And you are sure there is a remote branch by that _exact_ name? And that your local repo knows about it (i.e. you’ve `git fetch`ed)? What does `git branch -a` show? I can switch to a remote branch just fine with just `git checkout <branch>`, even with a slash in the name.

Comment: Can you paste the output generated in your terminal by `git pull origin feat/add_posts` ?
Do you see a message `* [new branch]      feat/add_posts -> origin/feat/add_posts` ?

Comment: I just reproduced your scenario in a test repo, and `git checkout feat/add_posts` worked for me. When you do `git branch -a`, do you see `remotes/origin/feat/add_posts` in the list? Your `git checkout --track origin/feat/add_posts` syntax also worked for me as expected. My only guess is that when you first tried it, you had not yet fetched or pulled that branch from `origin`.

Comment: Yes command `git branch -a` show remote branch as `remotes/origin/feat/add_posts`; And I have only one remote tracked repo: `git remote show; origin`

Comment: `git checkout -b feat/add_posts origin/feat/add_posts`.

Comment: seems to be a problem with the word `feat` and not with a slash, because with other words (`feature` or `fix`) everything works

Comment: Is there any chance that you have a branch called `feat` somewhere? If you a slash in your branch names, that creates directory with the name up to the slash, which is incompatible with also having that name as a branch. But this question is probably a red herring, the error message should have been different if that was the case. I still can't reproduce your original problem.

Comment: Yes. I have a lot of branches with prefix `feat/ ` on my local machine and on github. Therefore, it annoys me that I can not switch to the branch of another developer and check out his changes. Looking for one more clarification, I use Ubuntu and don't observe such a problem on the MacBook.